# GMSAutocompletePrediction prediction.attributedFullText not give nsmutablestring in swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift3, google-places-api, gmsautocomplete

I use GMSAutocompleteFetcher in my swift project to search places. Here I install  'GooglePlaces''GooglePlacePicker' 'GoogleMaps' with pods and write all things as in link 
https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete#use_the_fetcher
 but after write in textFieldDidChange I got result according to it in delegate method :

```
func didAutocomplete(with predictions: [GMSAutocompletePrediction]) {
        let resultsStr = NSMutableString()
        for prediction in predictions {
            resultsStr.appendFormat("%@\n", prediction.attributedFullText)

        }
```

but in resultsStr got value :

```
 Ca{
    GMSAutocompleteMatch = "<GMSAutocompleteMatchFragment: 0x608000223940>";
}lifornia{
}
```

It should be "California"

Comment: check my answer if you found your solution  then please upvote and accept

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Swift 3.0 code..**

Your `prediction.attributedFullText` attributed text to convert first in the `string` and then you get string type result.

```
   func didAutocomplete(with predictions: [GMSAutocompletePrediction]) {
    let resultsStr = NSMutableString()
    for prediction in predictions {
        resultsStr.appendFormat("%@\n", prediction.attributedPrimaryText.string)
    }
    print(resultsStr) //California
    }
```